# Tabs Outliner - restore information from backup files

Tags: google-chrome, backup, browser, google-chrome-extensions, history

I have been using Chrome extension Tabs Outliner for a few years without any problems but recently it has failed to load. When I try and open TO it just stays loading. Chrome tells me "page unresponsive" and that error message keeps showing up, and then a few minutes later TO crashes. And I have been trying to get TO to start for a few days now but the same keeps happening, and TO just won't load any information.

So is there a way I can get all the crashed session information from TO's backup files?
I have read [the extension creator's note here](https://groups.google.com/g/tabs-outliner-support-group/c/eKubL9Iw230/m/wQXOP1m90NoJ), and have backed up the files. The largest file in that folder is a txt file but it's not legible when I open it.

OS: Windows 11 Pro
Browser: Chrome

Answer (score -1):

have you tried clearing the browser cache? Sometimes this helps to clear up these types of issues.

Here is a guide if you aren't familiar with this task:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

Best of luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).